Inserting ggiraph plots into dataframe too slow
I have a list of ggiraph plots that I'd like to insert into a dataframe for future reactable rendering. There are about 100 plots in total that should be inserted into the corresponding 100 rows in the dataframe based on level1 and level2 name. (The list is consisted with 3 levels, while the last level is the plots.)
Below is a reproducible example.
library(tidyverse)
library(ggiraph)
library(purrr)

# plot is complicated and large
df_plt = as.data.frame(list('level1_name' = rep('x', 15), 'level2_name' = rep('a', 15), 'level3_name' = c(rep('Grade 1', 5), rep('Grade 2', 5), rep('Grade 3', 5)),
                         'trt' = rep(c('Placebo', 'Drug1', 'Drug2', 'Drug3', 'Drug4'), 3),
                         'value' = sample(1:10, 15, replace = TRUE),
                         'txt' = rep('hovering text', 15)))

level1 = unique(df_plt$level1_name)
level2 = unique(df_plt$level2_name)
plt_list =  
  purrr::set_names(level1) %>% 
  purrr::map(function(i)
  {
    df_plt_i <- df_plt %>% filter(level1_name %in% i)
    j <- unique(df_plt_i$level2_name)
    
    purrr::set_names(level2) %>% 
      purrr::map(function(j)
      {
        df_plt_i_j <- df_plt_i %>% filter(level2_name == j)
        plt = df_plt_i_j %>%
          ggplot(aes(x = trt, y = value, fill = trt, color = trt, linetype = fct_rev(level3_name))) +
          geom_bar_interactive(aes(alpha = fct_rev(level3_name),
                                   tooltip = txt),
                               position = 'stack',
                               stat = 'identity') +
          scale_linetype_manual(values = c('solid', 'solid', 'dashed')) +
          scale_fill_manual(values = c("#66c2a5", "#fc8d62", "#8da0cb", "#e78ac3", "#a6d854")) +
          scale_color_manual(values = c("#66c2a5", "#fc8d62", "#8da0cb", "#e78ac3", "#a6d854")) +
          scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.5, 0.2)) +
          labs(x = "", y = "", fill = '', alpha = "") +
          coord_flip() +
          theme_void() +
          theme(legend.position = 'none')
      })
    
  })

Inserting 1 plot roughly takes 0.1 sec. While I will need to do 100+ plots, it's taking over 10 sec (for this step solely, the previous step to generate 100 plots takes less than 3 sec).
# insert girafe plot into the dataframe - inserting 1 plot takes about 0.1 sec
df = as.data.frame(list('level1_name' = c('x'), 'level2_name' = c('a'), 'other_info' = c(tibble(1,2))))
df <- df %>%
  group_by(level1_name, level2_name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    gi = map2(level1_name, level2_name, ~ girafe(
      ggobj = plt_list[[.x]][[.y]],
      height_svg = 2,
      width_svg = 2.5,
      options = list(
        opts_tooltip(use_fill = TRUE),
        opts_toolbar(saveaspng = FALSE),
        opts_sizing(rescale = FALSE)
      )
    ))
  ) %>%
  unnest(data)

I'm wondering if there's any way that's faster to do this? Here I'm using map2(), but I've also tried rowwise() and it's taking about the same time. I'm not quite familiar with parallel computing and not sure if it works? But to my understanding, each worker needs to copy the dataset and the plot list first, which will probably take more time?

Just curious, why do you want to pre-generate the plots if it seems that generating the one you need on the fly might only take 0.1 sec?

Hi Jon, I don't need the plots elsewhere. I'm pre-generating them because I wasn't aware that I can directly generate them within a df using ggiraph package? Would that help with the speed?

Maybe you could take a step back and describe more your use case. Why do you want a data frame with 100 plots in it? How will you use it? Is there an approach where you can just keep the data and specifications for the plots and then use one or more functions to create the plots when you need them?

I'm trying to create a reactable style object and put it inside a shiny app. The purpose of this is to display a large table of different levels with all the summary plots and data. It's kind of a data dashboard. Right now everything else is working well, just that my shiny app using renderReactable is a little slow, so I came back and found the issue is actually the step to insert plots into reactable.
